# What is the correct way to display random images on table view cell

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to display random images on table view cell but when i scroll down and up images positions are changed.

I just added image on cell

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let imagesArr = ["img1","img2","img3","img4"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource,UITabBarDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...3)

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageCell") as! ImageCell
        cell.ImageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imagesArr[randomNumber])

        return cell

    }
}
```

I expect to get images where they were before scroll down and up

Comment: Are all images of the same size?

Comment: yes but that doesn't matter. for example, if image on first cell is "img3" when i scroll down and up i see that now it is changed and is "img2"

Comment: if you don't want them to change shuffle list and don't random itevery time you want to get a cell

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to set the image once and for all, you can do the following:

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...3)
        let imagesArr = ["img1","img2","img3","img4"]
        ImageView.image = UIImage(named: imagesArr[randomNumber])
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if random images should be changed if only you leave the page, then add random number in the viewDidLoad()

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

        let imagesArr = ["img1","img2","img3","img4"]

        var randomNumber = 0

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...3)
        }
    }

    extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource,UITabBarDelegate {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 10
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageCell") as! ImageCell
            cell.ImageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imagesArr[randomNumber])

            return cell

        }
```